# MVC FormsAuthentication is missing in Application_PostAuthenticateRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

Good day,

I'm trying to authenticate a user using FormsAuthentication  against AD.
I send the data via an ajax request to my controller,where the the authentication is performed. After the user is authenticated and a cookie is created and I try to access that cookie in the Application_PostAuthenticateRequest event in my Global.asax  but the cookie is always null .I'm not really sure if I'm doing this right and any pointers on it would be helpful.

here is my login

```
   $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            try {
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
               // debugger;
                var username = $("#Username").val();
                var pwd = $("#Password").val();
                //is username empty
                if (username==null) {
                    throw "User name cannot be Empty.";
                }


                if (pwd==null) {
                    throw "password cannot be Empty.";
                }

                param = {userName:username,password:pwd};

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Login/Authenticate",
                    data: JSON.stringify(param),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (msg, status, xhr) {
                        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                        //  $("#Data").text(msg.d);
                // debugger;
                        if (msg.Success) {
                                var url = '@Url.Action("BillRegisterMain", "Home")';
                                var url2 = '@Url.Content("~/Home/BillRegisterMain")'

                                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                                    window.location.href = url2;

                                }

                            return false;
                          }
                        else {
                          //  ////debugger;
                            showErrorMSg(msg.Message);
                            return false;
                            //alert("Error Authenticating.Please try again");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                      // ////debugger;
                        throw(msg.payload);
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
                showErrorMSg(e);
            }
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            return false;
        });
```

Here's my Controller:

```
  public JsonResult Authenticate()
    {
        try
        {
            var CustUser = new TTParlBillBook.Auth.AdAuthenticationService.CustomUser();
            var resolveRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
            var response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
            resolveRequest.InputStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string jsonString = new System.IO.StreamReader(resolveRequest.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            UsrObj _model = new UsrObj();
            _model = serializer.Deserialize<UsrObj>(jsonString);

            string username = _model.username;

            string password = _model.password;
            UserViewModel UserViewModel = new UserViewModel();

            string[] roles;
            string name = string.Empty;
            string pic = string.Empty;
            bool r = UserViewModel.Athenticate(username, password, out roles, out name, "", out pic, out CustUser);
            if (r)
            {
                UserViewModel.Username = username;
                UserViewModel.picture = pic;
                UserViewModel.roles = roles;
                 var userData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UserViewModel);
                //change this 
                 //CustUser.userName = username;
                 //CustUser.userPhoto = pic;
                 //Session["currentUser"] = CustUser;
                //create forms authentication ticket 
                 //System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
                 DateTime currentTdate = DateTime.Now;
                 var ticket = new System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, UserViewModel.Username, currentTdate, currentTdate.AddMinutes(15), true, userData);
                 var encTicket = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                 var faCookie = new HttpCookie(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
                 faCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                 faCookie.Secure = true;
                 response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);

                 //HttpCookie authCookie = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, true);
                 //authCookie.Value = encTicket;
                 //HttpCookie authCookie = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()
                 //authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                 //Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
            }
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new { Success = r,Message="Success" },
                ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new { Success = false,Message=ex.Message },
                ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet
            };
        }

    }
```

Here my Application_PostAuthenticateRequest in the global.asax

```
  protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported==true)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
                      if (authCookie != null)
                      {
                          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authCookie.Value))
                          {
                              FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                          }
                      }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

cookie in the controller:
[image]

cookie in Application_PostAuthenticateRequest:
[image]

Comment: I suspect after the NEXT request it will not be null - you cannot write and read a cookie in the same request. What ever you wrote wont necessarily be flushed down to the client to store at this time during the request

Comment: The next request is still null, you cannot write and read a cookie in the same request?..Ok how do I separate the read and write calls?

Comment: for the same request, you need to store it temporary in an object and refer to it.